# Custom Fieldable panels pane template rendering the Field collection items

Tags: 7, entities

I am using Fieldable Panels Panes (FPP). I created a custom FPP and I am using  Field Collection items into my custom FPP.

I want to customize the rendering of Field collection item fields in my FPP template file.

For example: fieldable-panels-pane--my_custom.tpl.php is my tpl file, where I am unable to customize my_field_collection_items fields seperately by using some classes.

Is there a way to customize these fields and render the output in desired way?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Actually, by using `$elements` in `.tpl` file, we get all variables and also all fields as an array. You can use it to render the output you want to.